# Shell script to highlight the difference like what is updated and added in between two csv file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Below is the two csv files, where we need to compare these two files against first column

```
 NewFile.csv
 -----------
data1,   A 
data2.5,  B 
data3,  C
data4.3, D
data5,  E
data6,  F

OldFile.csv
------------
data1,  A
data2,  B
data3,  C
data4,  D
data5,  E
```

And output file like below

```
OutputFile.csv
-------------
Updated
data2.5,    B
data4.3,    D
Added   
data6, F
```

I'm using below command to do that but it is just showing me all the difference, need to separate it out like what is update and newly added in the NewFile.csv

```
awk -F',' 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next};!($1 in a)'  NewFile.csv  OldFile.csv
```

output file of the above command  :-

```
data2.5,    B
data4.3,    D
data6, F
```

But I m looking for an output where I can clearly declare it that what is being added and updated in new one using shell script.

Comment: What's your field separator? Comma or tab or comma and tab or comma and multiple spaces?

Comment: Comma separator @Cyrus

Comment: When do you consider a record to be updated instead of added? Is a record updated, if it is in the same position as the old record, or is it updated if the second column is the same?

Comment: Is a record updated, if it is in the same position as the old record - Yes @Socowi

Answer (score 0):

The following script identifies lines that were

- **modified** (same line number in both files has different first fields)
- **added** (all line numbers from `NewFile.csv` that are not in `OldFile.csv`)

Deleted lines are not considered.

```
awk -F, -v oldfile=OldFile.csv 'BEGIN {print "Updated"}
{new0=$0; new1=$1; if (!added && !getline < oldfile) {print "Added"; added=1}}
!added && new1!=$1 {print new0}
added' NewFile.csv
```

For your example, this prints

```
Updated
data2.5,  B
data4.3, D
Added
data6,  F
```

`Updated` and `Added` are always printed, even if there were no such lines.